# Adding existing users from a table to a membership database

Tags: sharepoint, membership-provider, sharepoint-2013, sqlmembershipprovider, fba

We have an asp.net web application which maintains a table with user information, passwords and roles. I am trying to import this information to a Membership database and ultimately use them for Form Based Authentication in a Sharepoint 2013 web application. I also noticed that the Membership database which I created does not store passwords. At this point I am a bit confused as to how to proceed with creating a FBA for my sharepoint site using the same member credentials and roles from my existing table.

Answer (score 1):

It does actually store passwords. You probably have it configured for ‘hashed’ passwords – so you can’t actually see the passwords in the table – only a 1 way hash of the passwords. If you set the passwordFormat to Clear, the passwords will be in plain text within the db.

That being said, for security I do suggest you use Hashed. Do a search on google on how to hash your existing passwords so they can be put in the db in the correct format. But if you want to get it up and running quickly, use Clear and then Hash them in the future once you’ve got everything working.

And just a note - the password field is on the aspnet_Membership table.

Comment: Chris..I changed strategy, I already have a asp.net website which fetches credentials from the AD and stores them in a database table. Would I be able to create a custom membership provider for sharepoint which can authenticate users against this table?

The passwords in this table appear to be hashed and not plain text, do you think it would be possible for the sharepoint custom membership provider to authenticate plain text credentials against this table?